# Qbs Depends Item to affect products list

Tags: qbs

Assuming I have some project with tons of sub-projects, and in most cases I only need to compile few of them at once:

```
Project {
    property stringList plugins: ["plugin3", "plugin4"] // this is set externally
    references: plugins.map(function(p) { return "plugins/"+p+".qbs" })
}
```

Assuming `plugin3` depends on `plugin1` and `plugin2`:

```
Depends { name: "plugin1" }
Depends { name: "plugin2" }
```

In that case, I would have to set `plugins` property as:

```
plugins: ["plugin1", "plugin2", "plugin3", "plugin4"]
```

which is what I want to avoid. So, the question is: Is there a way to make subproject dependencies automatically added as project `references`?

p.s. there is also an alternative way to make all sub-projects present, but conditionally disabled. Can I somehow make them enabled by dependent sub-project?

Answer (score 0):

`references` should pretty much always be a static list; there is no need to make it conditional just because you only want to compile a certain subset of your products at once.

Instead, what you'll want to do is run qbs with the `-p` option which lets you specify the name of a particular product to build. Using this option will only built that product and its dependencies, but not the rest of the products in your project.

Comment: is it possible to set products passed to `-p` from project file or by settings project properties?

Comment: No, and there is no reason why you'd want to do that. However, if you're looking to exclude certain products from being built by default when you run `qbs build`, you can set the `builtByDefault` property of those products to `false`.

Comment: well, reasons are there when it comes to working in QtCreator. Basically, it's easier to set up references abovementioned way, than to manually run `qbs`

Comment: Well, in Qt Creator you can simply right click on a particular target to build only that target and its dependencies.